# Combine pipelines into one

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have 2 pipelines

Pipeline 1:

- Builds and Deploys a branch of our code to server1
- Starts the .exe by executing dotnet run command

Pipeline 2:

- Runs a test script from server 2 and sends requests to the exe started on server 1 in Pipeline 1
- stop the .exe on the server1

Goal is to combine these 2 pipelines into 1 or have it such a way that with one click both the pipelines will run where Pipeline 1 starts and then Pipeline 2 starts. What would be the best way to achieve this? Note that the Pipeline 1 is not considered complete as the .exe is running.

Comment: Hi Did you check out below solutions. How did it go with this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be leave it as it is and add step in pipeline 1 to trigger pipeline 2 over [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/Builds/Queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0
```

with this body

```
{
    "definition": {
        "id": 217
    },
    "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master",
    "sourceVersion": "",
    "reason": 1,
    "demands": [],
    "parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"true\"}"
}
```

([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#access-to-oauth-token) you have an example how to do this from powershell task)

or with this extension [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline)

You can also try to combine these two pipeline into one useing stages. To run both stages in parallel you need to have them independent, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-dependencies):

```yaml
stages:
- stage: FunctionalTest
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...

- stage: AcceptanceTest
  dependsOn: []    # this removes the implicit dependency on previous stage and causes this to run in parallel
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...
```

then if you trigger pipeline, both stages will run.

Third options is to use [pipeline triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) but for this approach I would recommend for you create two stages in first pipeline and use [stage filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-172-update#stages-filters-for-pipeline-resource-triggers).

Comment: Just now added this at the end of the question - Note that the Pipeline 1 is not considered complete as the .exe is running. Will the above approach still work? Thinking if the step to trigger pipeline should be added just before running the .exe

Comment: Sorry but this is really specific question which I'm a bit afraid that I'm not able to reply without detailed knowledge of your exe file. Howoever, if your exe waits for some requests keeping your pipeline alive, all should be fine if you trigger pipelines after `Builds and Deploys a branch of our code to server1`

Comment: What you can do to eb sure that all is up and running is to add some kind of test in pipeline2 to check if your app is running on server 1 and only then start tests and sending data. Of course put some timeout there to fail after some number of tries or fixed time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below workaround to combine the 2 pipelines into 1.

In the pipeline 1, you can open another command terminal to Start the .exe. For below example using [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7) in powershell script:

When the powershell task finish executing below command, the `dotnet run` command will be executed in a new poweshell window and the pipeline will continue to execute the following tasks.

```
Start-Process powershell  -ArgumentList "dotnet run ..."
```

Then you can add [PowerShell on target machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops) or [SSH Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops) in pipeline 1 to run the test script on server 2

See below simple example:

```
steps:

- powershell: |
    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "dotnet run ..."

- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
  inputs:
    Machines: 'server2'
    UserName: 'userName'
    UserPassword: '123456'
    InlineScript: |
      # Write your powershell commands here.
     
- powershell: |
    Stop-Process -Name processName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have both pipelines configured and running separately and that is the desired state then have one pipeline completion trigger the next one. Can do this by using [Pipeline Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Pipeline1 # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: Pipeline1Name # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

Pipeline1 is the name that your YAML will used to refer to the pipeline resource similar to a template in a another repository.

Source will be the name of the Pipeline as defined in your Azure Devops.